# Generally using anaconda, but install particular package from source

Tags: python, scipy, package, anaconda

In general I've transitioned to using anaconda (instead of macports) for managing my python packages -- this has been working great.  There are a couple of packages that I want to build directly from source, however (in particular [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org/)).  Are there any special considerations / procedures to take into account so that they'll play nicely together?  Do I need to uninstall the anaconda `scipy` first?

Comment: Please be careful not to create new overly broad tags like `development` (we could tag every question on Stack Overflow with that)! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to [build your own conda package](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/recipe.html). It is pretty simple:

1. `conda install conda-build`
2. `conda skeleton pypi mypackage` assuming there is a package `mypackage` on pypi
3. `conda build mypackage`
4. `conda install --use-local mypackage`

Now, you will get all the benefits of `conda`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  So if I was to update the package source - the conda script would handle rebuilding it?

Comment: Yes, just call `conda build` again. Added more details to my answer.

Comment: what if you want to install a package that's not on pypi? (in my case, it has a more up-to-date version than what's on pypi)

Comment: You can always [create them from scratch](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs2.html) without loading the data for the skeleton from PyPi..